# My print is warping: how can I ensure that it cools evenly?

Tags: adhesion, warping, cooling

My print is warping and I suspect it is because of uneven cooling.

How can ensure my print cools evenly? Should I put a fan on the bed? Will no fan and a tall skirt help?

Or are my edges curling up for another reason?

Comment: This seems more like a warping question than a cooling question to me.  There are methods to fix warping that do not involve cooling.  Are you looking for only cooling solutions or any warping solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without more information we cannot address what is causing your edges to turn up. This can depend on the model being printed, the process, the material, the bed, and the method used to bond it to the bed.

As far as the initial question, a fan will most certainly ensure *uneven* cooling.

The middle of the print is, and will remain, the warmest.  If you want the print to cool evenly, you'll need an enclosure to block out drafts and air currents, and you'll need to bring the heated bed temperature and enclosure temperature down slowly over a long period of time.

Comment: In addition to what Adam says... Some slicers also offer a feature called "shroud", that basically prints a disposable "shell" around the print proper, and is meant to trap warm air and make the print cool down much more gently (and thus evenly).